# I have 3 columns x,y and type. I'd like to find out if there's at least 3 connections of the same type on a grid using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a game table like:

```
CREATE TABLE game_piece(
  x Integer,
  y Integer,
  type Integer
);
```

Each (x,y) can only have 1 piece. Representing a grid (numbers being types):

```
1235
1134
9678
```

By connected I mean they have to be directly next to the origin in a vertical or horizontal fashion like:

```
 C   C=connected
COC  O=origin
 C
```

I'd like to check if there's 3 pieces connected anywhere on the grid without needing to get the whole grid of the database and doing it in python, if there's decent solution. Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "connected" ?

Comment: Do you want to know if there are atleast three different types for each x and y?

Comment: @ZaneBien Excellent comment! I've updated my question to illustrate.

Comment: @Madhivanan To clarify each (x,y) can only have 1 piece. Should've added a UNIQUE contraint.

Comment: So to clarify, what you're trying to do is 'find all squares that both contain a piece and is adjacent to at least two squares that contain a piece of the same type'

Comment: So you want to get ALL x and y coordinates where there are at least 3 "connected" pieces having the same type, right? You aren't going to be passing in the origin coordinates as (x,y) parameters right?

Comment: @ZaneBien I want to know if such a condition exists. I don't care so much about where or which cases qualify.

Comment: @Kit Sunde, wait, is the condition that there should be 3 adjacent pieces having the same of ***any*** type, or 3 adjacent pieces having the ***same*** type as the origin piece ?

Comment: @ZaneBien I'm trying to find 3 connected pieces of the same type. My exact use case is that I have green, blue and red in a game. The condition is to find if any same colored pieces are connected with at least 2 others.

Comment: +1 for this question by the way. We need more fun game-logic questions on here :)

Comment: @Braiba, yeah I wish we had more of these on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify my comments on Xophmeister's answer, like this:

```
SELECT o.x, o.y
FROM game_piece o
JOIN game_piece p
ON p.type = o.type
AND (
  (o.x = p.x AND p.y IN (o.y-1,o.y+1))
  OR
  (o.y = p.y AND p.x IN (o.x-1,o.x+1))
)
GROUP BY o.x, o.y
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

And here it is working on your test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0bd34/1

**Edit:** Since you only want to know *if* the condition exists, the best way to do it is to just shove `LIMIT 1` on the end and see whether the query returns a result or not. For some reason sqlfiddle doesn't like me putting the LIMIT in there, but I tested it on my server and it works just fine.

Comment: WOW we're really on the same page. Your answer looks similar to mine I'm currently working on.

Comment: Oh I've never seen sqlfiddle.com before, that's awesome.

Comment: @KitSunde Yeah, I only found out about it from an answer on here a couple of days ago. One of those sites you kick yourself for not having thought of yourself :P

Answer (score 1):

By 'connected', I'm going to assume you mean adjacent: That is, (5,3,1234) and (4,3,1234) would be connected.

As such, what you can do is join the table to itself twice, where each join depends on the one that preceded, and the conditions include:

```
on  nextPiece.type = lastPiece.type
and (nextPiece.x in (lastPiece.x - 1, lastPiece.x + 1)
or  nextPiece.y in (lastPiece.x - 1, lastPiece.x + 1))
```

Note that this doesn't consider diagonals as being adjacent.

The problem with this technique is that it will return duplicates: If record A is connected to record B, then both A and B will show in the result set. As you're joining twice, you'll see three duplicates... You can do a `select distinct` if all you are interested in is whether you've found a match, but the query in general will not be particularly fast either way (depending on how big your grid is and how sparsely it is populated).

**EDIT** See Braiba's solution (and comments, below): I made a mistake :P

Comment: Oh I didn't know you could use conditionals after `ON`, I've been filtering things out in the `WHERE` statement all this time. *Interesting*.

Comment: I think you're missing some conditions there; if the x value is adjacent to the piece you're not checking the y value and vise versa. Also, don't join twice: join once and filter down with GROUP BY .. HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: @Braiba You're right -- this is what I get for answering SO questions on the train! -- +1 goes to your answer from me. I particularly like your grouping solution: very neat :)

Comment: @Xophmeister As someone who does most of his SO answering on the bus, I know the feeling :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what do you mean by connected, you don't need to dump the whole db but only the 2 pieces on 4 directions.

```
select x, y, 
from game_piece 
where (
       (x between origin_x - 2 AND origin_x + 2 AND y = origin_y) 
    OR (y between origin_y - 2 AND origin_y + 2 AND x = origin_x)
      ) 
 AND type = the_type;
```

`origin_x`, `origin_y` are the coordinates of the piece you want to check.

That will dump between 1 and 8 pieces you'll have to check.

If the game table is very large, you should add an index on the x and y column, otherwise that might not be useful.

Hope it helps.

M.

Comment: I'm searching the whole grid to see if there's 3 that is connected at all. Which is how I figure out if there's a move to be made on the game board. As such I wouldn't query per x,y.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the number of different connection types:

```
select count(distinct type) as connections
from game_piece
where ((y = $y and x between $x - 1 and $x + 1)
  or (x = $x and y between $y - 1 and $y + 1))
and (x != $x or y != $y) -- exclude the origin itself
```

Comment: Ah sorry I think my title was misleading (updated now). I meant that I want to find out if 3 pieces that is of the same type is connected.

Comment: then add `and type = $type` and change to `count(*)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT 1
FROM game_piece
WHERE
    (x = $o_x AND y IN ($o_y + 1, $o_y - 1)) OR
    (y = $o_y AND x IN ($o_x + 1, $o_x - 1))
GROUP BY type
HAVING COUNT(1) = 3
```

`$o_x` and `$o_y` being the originX and originY input parameters respectively.

If there are exactly 3 pieces of the same type connected to the origin (either vertically or horizontally), this will return `1`, otherwise, it will return an empty result-set.

---

### Edit:

What you can try in order to find out if there's any pieces on the grid having 2 or more of the same adjacent types:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) > 0 AS doesExist
FROM
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM game_piece p
    INNER JOIN game_piece o ON
         p.type = o.type AND (
             (p.x = o.x AND p.y IN (o.y + 1, o.y - 1)) OR
             (p.y = o.y AND p.x IN (o.x + 1, o.x - 1))
         )
    GROUP BY p.type, o.x, o.y
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) a
```

Which will return `1` if there are one or more pieces and `0` if not.